Revtex 4.2, dvips, hyperref: broken bibliography links do not work
Sorry, I seem not to get this, even though I use tex and latex since 30 years. (And I read all messages on the topic.) I use, in my document:
\documentclass[onecolumn,nofootinbib,aps,prd,preprintnumbers,11pt,longbibliography,floatfix]{revtex4-2}          
\usepackage{xurl}          
\urlstyle{same}                  
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,breaklinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,linktoc=page]{hyperref}           
\usepackage[anythingbreaks]{breakurl}  

and dozens of other packages.
I compile with
latex file;
latex file;
latex file;
bibtex file;
latex file;
latex file;
latex file;
dvips file;
ps2pdf -dNOSAFER -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dFastWebView=true  file.ps file.pdf 

because all my images exist as svg and eps files only.
Nevertheless, the links that are broken over two lines in the bibliography do not work. I suspect that I have an old work habit that is wrong.
What is the simplest way to get working links that span two lines in the bibliography of the pdf?
The unbroken links, which are on one line only, work perfectly.
Thank you in advance!

Without a complete example it is not possible to test your issue. Try to compile with pdflatex (and without the breakurl package), it normally handles eps nowadays.

This works - the bibliography is ok now. But psfrag does not work any more. What do I need to do with pdflatex to get it running?

For psfrag you need dvips. So you should make a complete example that demonstrates your problem.

@KlausK you can try if it works with pdflatex and the auto-pst-pdf package, this package creates (automatically, as the name says) a latex-dvips run just for the psfrag parts and inserts the result in the main document which is processed by pdflatex itself. The package needs shell-escape to run (because it calls latex in the background).

Thank you very much to all of you! The combination of pdflatex and the auto-pst-pdf package solved the problem. This is fantastic and solves many issues I had for such a long time!

As explained in the comments, the combination of using
pdflatex -shell-escape

and
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

in the header solves the problem. (However, the pdf file size is almost doubled.)

The dvips driver of hyperref does not support broken links. This is a limitation of the program dvips. The program pdfTeX supports broken links. There are also some limitations, but it should work most of the times. Therefore, running the example with pdfTeX (pdflatex) has solved the broken link problem of the question.
